# How to get datetime automatically by using service in Android

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I have been making an Note application with alarm function

Every note has an datetime for alarm. Ex : Note1 with 22-8-2017 19:00:00 then at 19:00:00 the alarm must be executed.

I want use Service to get current datetime automatically. This mean my service is always running in background and auto get datetime to execute Alarm with datetime remind per note. But when I press button Create note and start service, the datetime is just get one time

Example: I have a Note with remind datetime is 22-8-2017 19:00:00 and it was created at 22-8-2017 16:00:00. Follow lôgic, after press Create button the Note will be created without alarm. My service is still runing in background (always get datetime to compare with remind date of note that has created), get datetime of notes in database and get system datetime untill they are the same then Alarm will be execute.

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf4 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    datestring = sdf4.format(date);

        mdate = sdf4.parse(datestring);
```

Comment: tks for your response but no, I mean since I start my Apllication at the first time then the service is always running in back-ground. Mission of this service is get current datetime daily at verry hour and minute and second, I emphasize that every hour and minute and second to compare to all remind date of note that is in database. This mean service always get system datetime. Not the one times........it is daily and every time

Comment: It mean the service always do some things. Example : Application 1 fetch data from another Application daily and this process is execute in background without starting from any interaction such as press button,....etc. I give another example is virus . The virus auto get your data that you don't know. So, my target is the same (not virus)

Answer (score 1):

You can use timer as given below:

```
public void getTimeForEachSecond() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                mins = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Current Time is " + hours + ":" + mins + ":" + seconds);
                    }
                });

            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i got it...so u can do this...

```
private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run()

        {
            gettime();

            Home_Fragment.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 50000);
        }

    };
```

then after create gettime method outside the create method...

```
 public void gettime()
    {
        long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf4 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        datestring = sdf4.format(date);
        try {
            try {
                mdate = sdf4.parse(datestring);
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            long unixTime = (long) mdate.getTime() / 1000 + 19800;
            Log.e("unixtime: ", "> " + unixTime);
            x = (int) unixTime;
            Log.e("x: ", "> " + x);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: gettime update at every 50 seconds..because i use 50000 milliseconds at.....Home_Fragment.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 50000);

Comment: It mean to use thread then the getting date function is always run in background, is not it ?

Comment: Actually, Android support AlarmManager with setRepeat method but I don't know the alarm will be loop in how many times exactly and my app has many Note, every note may be has 0 or many times to loop so I must to use get current datetime automatically daily and verytime

Comment: 30 minutes is default. Example : my Note 1 was created at 22-8-2017 17:00 and has reminder date is 22-8-2017 20:00 (A)  and 3 times of reminding (B) . So service will run and check every time whether is same to (A), if they are same (20:00) then an Alarm will be execute and every 30 minutes Alarm will re-remind within 3 times. That 's all=> my goal

Comment: ohk...so get time update every 1000 second..use  Home_Fragment.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 1000);

Comment: what is the Home_Fragment.this.mHandler.postDelayed ?

Comment: home_fragment means your activity name...in which activity name u have to update this time yr..it is so simple..

Comment: Hi DEVYANI....I am Vietanamese developer. I had found out your facebook. Could I addfriend you? We can discuss much more about programming

Comment: I think I find out my solution without using thread. Android support all!!! tks a lots, thank all people for your help